# How to add value into Arraylist<Integer>?

Tags: java

I'm trying to add whatever value that scanner read from the file into an `ArrayList<Integer>`, but for some reason it doesn't work; it keeps complaining that "java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer."

Can anyone help me what is wrong with this? It works with the String type of Arraylist but not with Integer types of arraylist. So, I am guessing this is the problem, but not exactly know what is going on.

```
/**
 * readFromFile method will read from the database file and save all usernames, 
 * passwords, and keys in the corresponding ArrayLists.If the file cannot open,
* output error message: <dbName> cannot open!
 * @param dbName The file name to save all users, passwords, and keys
 * @param users
 * @param pwds
 * @param keys
 */
public static void readFromFile(String dbName, ArrayList<String> users, ArrayList<String> pwds, ArrayList<Integer> keys) {
    Path path = Paths.get("dbName");
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(dbName +"cannot"+ " open!");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {
        users.add(scan.next());
        pwds.add(scan.next());
        keys.add(scan.next()); // This is where the problem occurs
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Integer.parseInt`?

Comment: keys.add( Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); you need to convert from a string to a number.

Comment: A `String` is not an `Integer`. Why do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1):

- The variable `keys` is defined as `ArrayList<Integer>`.
- The output of `scan.next()` is a `String`.

The compiler recognizes this and so it will not allow you to insert a `String` into a `List<Integer>`.  You need to parse the `Integer` out of the `String` prior to insertion or invoke the int-specific method on the `Scanner`.

```
keys.add(Integer.valueOf(scan.next()));
... or ....
keys.add(scan.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nextInt` or to parse string value.

```
keys.add(scan.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

correct to    `keys.add(Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())`

```
public static void readFromFile(String dbName, ArrayList<String> users, ArrayList<String> pwds, ArrayList<Integer> keys) {
    Path path = Paths.get("dbName");
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(dbName +"cannot"+ " open!");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {
        users.add(scan.next());
        pwds.add(scan.next());
       keys.add(Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()) // This is where the problem occurs
    }
```

Comment: Using `nexLine()` instead of `next()` in the original code will change the behaviour of the code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thankyou for correcting me then what we use?
Next() function?

Comment: Given the OP is using `next()` (which returns a String), then you should as well (or switch to `nextInt()`)